# Using Wrapfig2 inside a tcolorbox

Tags: graphics, tcolorbox, text, wrap, wrapfig2

I have a `tcolorbox` with some text and I would like to use `wrapfig2` to wrap two images inside the box, both surrounded by the text, one image in the upper left corner of the box and the second one in the lower right corner of the box. I succeed to wrap the first one, but I have difficulty to wrap the second one which is printed outside the box beside its code is inside the box. What I am missing here, and how can I achieve what I want?

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Scale=1.1}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,blindtext,wrapfig2}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[]
        
        \begin{wrapfigure}[9]{l}{0.25\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
                \setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}%
                \vspace{-6mm}
                \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
            \end{center}
            \caption{\footnotesize Image A}
        \end{wrapfigure}
        
        \blindtext[3]
        
        \begin{wrapfigure}[9]{r}{0.25\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
                \setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}%
                \vspace{-6mm}
                \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
            \end{center}
            \caption{\footnotesize Image B}
        \end{wrapfigure}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have no text after the second wrapfigure so there is nothing that can be wrapped.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I want the image to be wrapped by the last 9 lines of the text, as like the first 9 lines of the first image. I tried several different positions of the image without success.

Comment: you can't go back and re-shape previous paragraphs, you need to put the wrapfig before the text that is to go round it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always need to give the figure *before* the paragraph text so the paragraph shape can be set.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Scale=1.1}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,blindtext,wrapfig2}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[]
        
        \begin{wrapfigure}[9]{l}{0.25\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
                \setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}%
                \vspace{-6mm}
                \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
            \end{center}
            \caption{\footnotesize Image A}
        \end{wrapfigure}
        


Hello, here is some text without a meaning. This text should show what a printed text
will look like at this place. If you read this text, you will get no information. Really? Is there
no information? Is there a difference between this text and some nonsense like ``Huardest
gefburn''? Kjift -- not at all! A blind text like this gives you information about the selected
font, how the letters are written and an impression of the look. This text should contain all
letters of the alphabet and it should be written in of the original language. There is no need
for special content, but the length of words should match the language. Hello, here is some
text without a meaning. This text should show what a printed text will look like at this place.
If you read this text, you will get no information. Really? Is there no information? Is there
a difference between this text and some nonsense like ``Huardest gefburn''? Kjift -- not at
all! A blind text like this gives you information about the selected font, how the letters are
written and an impression of the look. This text should contain all letters of the alphabet and
it should be written in of the original language. There is no need for special content, but the
length of words should match the language. Hello, here is some text without a{\parfillskip=0pt\par}

        \begin{wrapfigure}[9]{r}{0.25\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
                \setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}%
                \vspace{-6mm}
                \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
            \end{center}
            \caption{\footnotesize Image B}
        \end{wrapfigure}
\noindent  meaning. This
text should show what a printed text will look like at this place. If you read this text, you will
get no information. Really? Is there no information? Is there a difference between this text
and some nonsense like ``Huardest gefburn''? Kjift -- not at all! A blind text like this gives
you information about the selected font, how the letters are written and an impression of the
look. This text should contain all letters of the alphabet and it should be written in of the
original language. There is no need for special content, but the length of words should match
the language.

        

    \end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```